# Passing post parameters with jQuery.post

Tags: jquery, ajax, parameters

I have a regular anchor tag which is bound to a $.post() but I'm having trouble wrapping my head around the best way to pass along parameters. Here's what I've got:

```
<a 
href="ajax/tag_delete.php?id=<?php echo $tag->id;?>" <!-- This feels too "GET" and I don't want to have to parse this query string -->
id="<?php echo $tag->id;?>" <!-- this feels wrong, shouldn't have a number as an id  --> 
class="delete_tag_btn">
delete
</a>

<script>
    $('.delete_tag_btn').bind('click', function(event){
        event.preventDefault();
        $.post( this.href, {/* WHAT IS THE BEST WAY TO GET THESE */}, function(reply) {
            log(reply);
        });
    });
</scirpt>
```

Any help is much appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: This is a pretty simplified example. What if I wanted to pass multiple parameters. Along these lines:ajax/tag_delete.php?id=10&foo=bar&blue=red;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`$(this).attr('href').split('=')[1]`

Of course, that's dependent on your url having a single querystring parameter. If needed, you can get a little more fancy, but this solves your immediate problem.

**Edit:**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.delete_tag_btn').bind('click', function(event){
        event.preventDefault();

        var s = $(this).attr('href').split('?')[1].split('&');
        var a = new Object();

        for(var n = 0; n < s.length; ++n)
        {
            var t = s[n].split('=');
            console.log(String(t[0]));
            a[String(t[0])] = t[1];
        }

        console.log(a);
    });
});
```

Given the edit, you can specify any number of attributes in your `href`, which will then be passed to your `post`. In other words, you can use this function *anywhere* throughout your application and you don't need to specify which keys to get:

```
$.post( 
     this.href, 
     data: a, 
     function(reply) {
            log(reply);
});
```

Comment: Thanks Demian, but I'm looking for a more robust solution.

Comment: @pardoner: why didn't you say so? ;) see edit (i know you've already accepted an answer, but the above is quite a bit more flexible)

Comment: @Damian,  thanks, this will work. I guess I was looking for something a little more standard - best practice. Is this a pretty standard way of dong it?

Comment: @pardoner: not too sure whether or not there's a *standard* way of doing it - some people will use regex for this kind of thing, but it's not needed (regex is slower than native string functions).

Answer (score 0):

Actually, that *should* work.  You might need to remove the empty object argument and switch to a .get call...

```
$.get(this.href, function(reply){
   // Do whatever
});
```

On the other hand, you can always create an object...

```
var data = {
   id: $(this).attr('id')
}
```

Then pass it in your .post call...

```
$.post(this.href, data, function(reply){
   // Do whatever...
})
```